# regular expression gone wrong

Tags: php, regex

I want to find all strings looking like `[!plugin=tesplugin arg=dfd arg=2!]` and put them in array.
Important feature: the string could contain `arg=`uments or NOT(in some cases). and of course there could be any number of `arg`'s. So the string could look like:
`[!plugin=myname!]` or `[!plugin=whatever1 arg=22!]` or even `[!plugin=gal-one arg=1 arg=text arg=tx99!]`. I need to put them all in `$str`array items

Here is what i did...

```
$inp = "[!plugin=tesplugin arg=dfd!] sometxt [!plugin=second arg=1 arg=2!] 1sd";
preg_match_all('/\[!plugin=[a-z0-9 -_=]*!]/i', $inp, $str);
```

but `$str[0][0]` contains:

```
[!plugin=tesplugin arg=dfd!] sometxt [!plugin=second arg=1 arg=2!]
```

instead of putting each expression in a new array item.. 
I think my problem in regex.. but can't find one. Plz help...

Comment: omg! so silly mistake!)))) thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The last `]` needs to be escaped and the `-` in the character class needs to be at the start, end, or escaped.  As is it is a range of ascii characters between a space and underscore.

```
\[!plugin=[a-z0-9 \-_=]*!\]
```

Regex101 Demo: https://regex101.com/r/zV4bO2/1